# SSRS report not rendering while passing parameter in URL

Tags: string, url, reporting-services, parameters, reporting

I am very new to SSRS.
I am trying to invoke an ssrs report using URL parameters.
It is not heklping.here is the URL I am using http://xyzabc/ReportServer2/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReportName%2fTimesheetBCC&rs:Command=Render&QueryGNAME='abc'&QueryCentreName='xyz'&QueryWeekType='Week'&QuerySiteLocation='Off'&QuerySUBBU='All'

This is not loading(Rendering) the report. It is still prompting for the Parameters. If I select manually, it works.

I am stuck for last two days. A little help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need those single quotes in the url for the parameter values and there is no output format specified. Clear Session is not there either which prevents caching of parameters. If the report is in a folder in SSRS then replace SSRS_Folder in link below with the name of the folder so it can find the report.Try this:

http://xyzabc/ReportServer2/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSSRS_Folder%2fReportName%2fTimesheetBCC&QueryGNAME=abc&QueryCentreName=xyz&QueryWeekType=Week&QuerySiteLocation=Off&QuerySUBBU=All&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rs:ClearSession=true

Comment: I found this issue where there is a cascading parameter is present

Comment: This also didnt work. I hope this issue is because of cascading parameters. I have tried the same with another SSRS report with single Parameter and it worked pretty well. I am facing issue wjere there is a cascading parameter. Any Idea how to remove the cascading parameters? I am using SSAS(MS Tabular) for source

Comment: Check the order of your parameters. They should be ordered by the largest number to records to the smallest. i.e. Category, Subcategory, Item.